# A confusing while loop in Java

Tags: java

Let's look at the following day-to-day example of Java.

```
package loop;

final public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         long temp=1000000000;

        while(temp--!=0)
        {
            temp-=temp++;
            System.out.println("Inside loop = "+temp);
        }
        System.out.println("Outside loop = "+temp);
    }
}
```

---

In the above simple code, the **while** loop iterates over only once though the local variable **temp** of type **long** contains a large value which is **1000000000**.

---

Through the statement `System.out.println("Inside loop = "+temp);`, it displays **Inside loop = 0** and through this statement `System.out.println("Outside loop = "+temp);`, it displays **Outside loop = -1**. Why is it so?

Comment: `while(temp--!=0)` gets executed once more before the loop is terminated

Comment: temp -= temp++; it's lines like these that give me a headache.

Comment: `for (temp = 1000000000; temp >= 0; temp--)` is better

Comment: @mikejones That won't exhibit the same behavour because temp is not reduced by one each step

Comment: @Lion is this puzzle code you are trying to understand or real code you are trying to fix?

Comment: @Bob Vale:) Please, don't mind at all about my saying but I just play with some tricky codes in Java believing that it may make my way of learning Java more interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because when it hits the while loop for the last time, it does a temp--

ie....  temp == 0, so it will quit the while loop,  and do a -- after the comparison.

the joys of post increment/decrement.

Answer (score 2):

`temp--` inspects the contents then decreases the value

so if temp==0

`temp--!=0` returns false because temp==0;  But straight after the comparison temp is reduced to -1

if you change the while loop to read

```
while (--temp!=0)
```

Then you will find inside and outside the loop have the same value

EDIT -- (I missed the a bit about why one loop)

```
temp-=temp++;
```

This is reducing temp by temp, written longer

```
temp = temp - (temp++);
```

because the evaluation is performed after reading its value, this ends up becoming

```
temp = temp - temp;
```

or by elimination

```
temp = 0;
```

I am uncertain as to the defined behaviour for an assignment with an incrementor of the same variable on the right hand side but from your explaination of the results you are getting I would assume that the left hand assignent is taking precedence over the right hand side.  This may be moving into undefined territory and definitely should be avoided.

Comment: while (--temp!=0) gets stuck into an infinite loop.

Comment: @Lion, looking at it yes it will, because the logic inside will never let it work.
Loop1: temp will change to 999999999 inside while condition (before evaluation) and 0 during while body
Loop2: temp will change to -1 inside while condition (before evaluation) and 0 during while body
Loopn: repeat loop2 add infinitum

Answer (score 1):

After `while(temp--!=0)` have been evaluated it will decrease the variable `temp` by one. Simply put: During the evaluation it will be zero but as soon as the variables has been used it will be decreased.

Answer (score 1):

The last operation before the system out println from the outer loop is temp--!=0 so you are decrementing the value to -1.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
temp-=temp++;
```

You make `temp` zero, and afterwards, in this line:

```
while(temp--!=0)
```

The test returns `false` and the loop exists, but right befor exiting, `temp` is decremented one last time, ending with a `-1` value